# StringTemplate gives wrong answer

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation

Consider this:

```
StringTemplate["``"][-0.9999995]
(*"-0.1"*)
```

Is this a bug?

I'm using version 11.0 on OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Also happens in V10.4.1 -- pretty much a bug, I would think.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `TextString`.

Comment: FYI: reported to wolfram with [CASE:3698059].

Comment: Doesn't happen with `StringForm["``", -0.9999995]`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm not sure they are the same bug. `StringTemplate["``"][-0.9999995]` gave `0.9999995` in version 10.0.1. But `StringTemplate["``"][NumberForm[1000/81, 10]]` gave correct result in version 10.0.1.