# StringTemplate doesn't work with negative numbers

Tags: bugs, output-formatting, string-manipulation

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

<sub>Bug isn't present in version 10.0.1</sub>

---

I'm using *Mathematica* 10.4 on Windows 7 and I found out that

```
StringTemplate["``"][NumberForm[1000/81, 10]]
```

Gives

> ```
> "12.34567901"
> ```

Which is correct, but

```
StringTemplate["``"][NumberForm[-1000/81, 10]]
```

Only returns with the rounded integer

> ```
> "-12"
> ```

I need to print an array of positive and negative numbers in a specific format.
 How I can bypass this problem?

Comment: This question is very similar to [(125006)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125006/142).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `StringTemplate`. One workaround is to preliminarily convert `NumberForm` into string by applying `ToString`. Note that `NumberForm` isn't intended for working with exact rationals and hence you need also to apply `N` to the first argument of `NumberForm`:

```
StringTemplate["``"][ToString@NumberForm[N[-1000/81], 10]]
```

> ```
> "-12.34567901"
> ```

Here is a minimal working example demonstrating the bug (the output is identical in versions 10.4.1 and 11.0.0):

```
StringTemplate["``"][NumberForm[N[-1000/81], 10]]
```

> ```
> "-12"
> ```

Version 10.0.1 has no bug and creates correct output even without applying `N` to the first argument of `NumberForm`:

```
StringTemplate["``"][NumberForm[-1000/81, 10]]
```

> ```
> "-12.34567901"
> ```

Comment: More specifically the bug was in `TextString` which is the default `InsertingFunction` for `StringTemplate`: `TextString@NumberForm[-1000/81, 10]`.